# should I use shared memory in "stock trading" system to separate "market data receiver" part?

Tags: c#

My trading system consists of two parts

- "Udp milticast market data receiver" - just receives market data from UDP multicast and nothing else(orderbooks, orders, best bid/ask etc.)
- "Main system" - uses market data, calculates new orders, send orders etc etc.

These systems are pretty connected - typical scenario is something like that:

```
- "UDP" -> "Main" Apple BID/ASK 500.1/500.2
- Main sends order № 1122 Apple BUY 555
- "UDP" -> "Main" Order № 1122 Executed
- Main send order № 1123 Apple SELL 505
- "UDP" -> "Main" Order №1123 Registered, Ammount 1, Executed 0, Left 1
```

"UDP" part doesn't know that "Main" exist.
"Main" uses "UDP"

I want to make these to be separate projects because theoretically I can run "UDP" itself without running "Main". Or I can run several "Main" instances.

So "UDP" should produce some writable storage that others can use.

But "Main" and "UDP" are pretty connected - they use the same classes and same structures to represent `Quotes` etc.

And I also can't have perfomance penalty, perfomance is very important I need something as fast as just storing data inside application.

Should I use "shared memory" or other techniques or it's better to make everything in one project?

I think my problem is pretty general because a lot of different market data adapters already written by different companies so there should be some "default" solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need performance, the solution is use ine single project with clearly separated layers. Whatever "detached" solution you would choose, there will be *always* some overhead.

On other part, detauching could help you scale up an application in a way that, may be, one day  "Main" could be not on the same machine where "Udp" is. Look on `.NetRemoting` to achieve that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how much "overhead" will I have? I can pay 0.05 ms

Comment: I believe noone can give an answer on this. Performance issues are *strongly* coupled with the current program context. So this is something you should figure out by yourself.

Comment: i think "overhead" of shared files should be known